# ArrayList.remove() is not removing object

Tags: java, arraylist, getter-setter

I have an ArrayList with the object Player. When I try to remove this object from the list, I do not get any errors in the console, but the object is not being removed. This is because if I System.out.println(ArrayList); after I remove the object, it still prints out the object that was just removed.

I manage and create the ArrayList here:

```
public class CreatureManager {

    protected Handler handler;

    private ArrayList<Creature> creatures;
    private final Player player;

    public CreatureManager(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
        player = new Player(handler, 1280, 720);
        creatures = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addCreature(Creature e) {
        creatures.add(e);
    }

    public void removeCreature(Creature e) {
        creatures.remove(e);
    }

    public void tick() {
        for (Creature e : creatures) {
            e.tick();
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        for (Creature e : creatures) {
            e.render(g);
        }
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public ArrayList<Creature> getCreatures() {
        return creatures;
    }

}
```

The generic "Creataure" in the ArrayList is referring to the following class:

```
public abstract class Creature {

    protected Handler handler;

    protected int x, y;
    protected int width, height;
    protected Rectangle bounds;

    public Creature(Handler handler, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    public abstract void tick();

    public abstract void render(Graphics g);

}
```

The object (Player) in the arraylist is added here, and is called when the program is first ran:

```
    public void renderCreatures() {
        handler.getCreatureManager().addCreature(new Player(handler, 1280, 720));
    }
```

The object (Player) in the arraylist is being removed, and the arraylist (which is being called with a getter called getPlayer() which returns the arraylist) is being printed to the console afterwards as such:

```
handler.getCreatureManager().removeCreature(handler.getCreatureManager().getPlayer());
System.out.println(handler.getCreatureManager().getCreatures());
```

The output in the console (from the Sysout of the arraylist) proves that the object that was just removed is still in the arraylist:

```
[dev.l0raxeo.entities.creatures.Player@3661db4d]
```

Comment: I'd look on how equals() method on Player class is implemented because it's being used during removal. If it always return false, then the object won't be found in a list and won't be removed.

Comment: Added `Player` object and the  `Player` object you are trying to remove are different. Try adding `handler.getCreatureManager().addCreature(handler.getCreatureManager().getPlayer());` this way.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I'm a self taught programmer and I'm only 13 so I'm not too sure what you guys are suggesting I do...

Comment: You need to implement to equals(Object o) method for Player, as well as the hashCode() method.

Comment: Thank you all I solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `renderCreatures`, you're adding a `new Player` but not saving a reference to it anywhere (such as in the `player` field), so when you call `getPlayer()`, that's returning a different `Player` object. (If you printed `getPlayer()`, you'd see that it's a different instance.)

Instead, just go ahead and add the `player` to your list in the constructor where you're creating it.